# Fill the data on the missing date range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table will the data with exist data below:

```
Select Date, [Closing Balance] from StockClosing

Date     | Closing Quantity
---------------------------
20200828 | 5 
20200901 | 10
20200902 | 8    
20200904 | 15
20200905 | 18
```

There are some missing date on the table, example 20200829 to 20200831 and 20200903.
Those closing quantity of the missing date will be follow as per previous day closing quantity.

I would like select the table result in a full range of date (show everyday) with the closing quantity. Expected result,

```
Date     | Closing Quantity
---------------------------
20200828 | 5 
20200829 | 5
20200830 | 5 
20200831 | 5 
20200901 | 10
20200902 | 8    
20200903 | 8    
20200904 | 15
20200905 | 18
```

Beside using cursor/for loop to insert the missing date and data 1 by 1, is that any SQL command can do it at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have option to use recursive CTE.

**For reference [Click Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=77fbd4ebc2993dd6a3782d55488f2de0)**

```
;with cte as(
select max(date) date from YourTable
),cte1 as (
select min(date) date from YourTable
union all
select dateadd(day,1,cte1.date) date from cte1 where date<(select date from cte)
)select c.date,isnull(y.[Closing Quantity], 
    (select top 1 a.[Closing Quantity] from YourTable a where c.date>a.date order by a.date desc) )
        as [Closing Quantity]
from cte1 c  left join YourTable y on c.date=y.date
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to use `LAST_VALUE` along with the `IGNORE NULLS` option.  Sadly, SQL Server does not support this.  There is a workaround using analytic functions, but I would actually offer this simple option, which uses a correlated subquery to fill in the missing values:

```
WITH dates AS (
    SELECT '20200828' AS Date UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200829' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200830' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200831' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200901' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200902' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200903' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200904' UNION ALL
    SELECT '20200905'
)

SELECT
    d.Date,
    (SELECT TOP 1 t2.closing FROM StockClosing t2
     WHERE t2.Date <= d.Date AND t2.closing IS NOT NULL
     ORDER BY t2.Date DESC) AS closing
FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN StockClosing t1
    ON d.Date = t1.Date;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer works. However, how to modify the answer to accommodate two values for the same date? 
 ps. Currently the code uses 'TOP 1' so, the second 'closing' value will be ignored
eg:
WITH StockClosing AS (
SELECT '20200828' AS Date, 5 AS closing UNION ALL
SELECT '20200828', 55 UNION ALL ---- same date as '5' 
SELECT '20200828', 66 UNION ALL ---- same date as '5' 
SELECT '20200901', 10 UNION ALL
SELECT '20200901', 16 UNION ALL ---- same date as '10' 
SELECT '20200902', 8  UNION ALL
SELECT '20200904', 15 UNION ALL
SELECT '20200905', 18
)

Therefore required output:
(please note '5', '55', '66' all repeated for the same date range,  and similarly '10','16' repeated for the same date range)

20200828    5
20200829    5
20200830    5
20200831    5
20200828    55
20200829    55
20200830    55
20200831    55
20200828    66
20200829    66
20200830    66
20200831    66
...
20200901    10
20200901    16
...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).